# Common Lisp add suffix to symbol for use in macros

Tags: common-lisp

How do you introduce new, predictably named identifiers with suffixes in a macro?

---

So, I'm writing a simple library for manipulating quaternions. I'm using the simplest representation that could possibly work, a list of components, for the time being, but I'd like to define a simple API that doesn't depend on that representation.

When defining algorithms, I want to refer to each of the components of the quaternion with a predictable name like `somesymbol-realpart` or `somesymbol-i`.

I'd like to be able to get the following snippet to work.

```
(let
     ((my-quat '(1 2 3 4)))
  (with-quaternion my-quat
           (assert-equalp 1 my-quat-realpart)
           (assert-equalp 2 my-quat-i)
           (assert-equalp 3 my-quat-j)
           (assert-equalp 4 my-quat-k)))
```

However, the method I used for producing a symbol with a suffix seems to produce strange case-sensitive symbols with escaped uppercase characters.

```
(defun add-suffix-to-symbol (sym suffix)
  (intern (concatenate 'string "" (string sym) "-" suffix)))
```

As a result of converting a symbol to a string, it is printed in uppercase... which is a totally valid canonicalization. However, creating a new symbol via `intern` preserves the case for some reason, so I have to do something like the following to refer to bindings introduced by `with-quaternion`.

```
(let
    ((my-quat '(1 2 3 4)))
  (with-quaternion my-quat
           (assert-equalp 1 |MY-QUAT-realpart|)
           (assert-equalp 2 |MY-QUAT-i|)
           (assert-equalp 3 |MY-QUAT-j|)
           (assert-equalp 4 |MY-QUAT-k|)))
```

How do I create a new symbol that's identical to an old one but with a suffix so that it can be used in a macro?

for reference, here is all the code.

```
(defun assert-equalp (e a)
  (assert (equalp e a)))

(defun quat-realpart (q)
  (first q))

(defun quat-i (q)
  (second q))

(defun quat-j (q)
  (third q))

(defun quat-k (q)
  (fourth q))

(assert-equalp '1 (quat-realpart '(1 2 3 4)))
(assert-equalp '2 (quat-i '(1 2 3 4)))
(assert-equalp '3 (quat-j '(1 2 3 4)))
(assert-equalp '4 (quat-k '(1 2 3 4)))

(defun add-suffix-to-symbol (sym suffix)
  (intern (concatenate 'string "" (string sym) "-" suffix)))

(print (add-suffix-to-symbol 'a "suffix"))

(defgeneric with-quaternion-impl (q-sym body))

(defmethod with-quaternion-impl ((q-sym symbol) body)
  (let
      ((q-realpart (add-suffix-to-symbol q-sym "realpart"))
       (q-i (add-suffix-to-symbol q-sym "i"))
       (q-j (add-suffix-to-symbol q-sym "j"))
       (q-k (add-suffix-to-symbol q-sym "k")))
    `(let
     ((,q-realpart (quat-realpart ,q-sym))
      (,q-i (quat-i ,q-sym))
      (,q-j (quat-j ,q-sym))
      (,q-k (quat-k ,q-sym)))
       (progn ,@body))))


(defmacro with-quaternion (q-sym &rest body)
  (with-quaternion-impl q-sym body))


(let
    ((my-quat '(1 2 3 4)))
  (with-quaternion my-quat
           (assert-equalp 1 |MY-QUAT-realpart|)
           (assert-equalp 2 |MY-QUAT-i|)
           (assert-equalp 3 |MY-QUAT-j|)
           (assert-equalp 4 |MY-QUAT-k|)))

(let
    ((my-quat '(1 2 3 4)))
  (with-quaternion my-quat
           (assert-equalp 1 my-quat-realpart)
           (assert-equalp 2 my-quat-i)
           (assert-equalp 3 my-quat-j)
           (assert-equalp 4 my-quat-k)))
```

When run under `clisp`, it prints the following symbol, clearly with escaped uppercase characters.

```
|A-suffix|
```

and produces the following error message:

```
*** - PROGN: variable MY-QUAT-REALPART has no value
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Symbols in common lisp are interned in uppercase by default. The apparent case insensitivity is because everything you type is converted to uppercase at read/retrieval time, unless you use the special syntax with bar characters `|My-case-sensitive-SYMBOL|`. `my-case-insensitive-symbol` and `MY-CASE-INSENSITIVE-SYMBOL` refer to the same interned symbol, which is stored in all uppercase (though, this being common lisp, it is often possible to change that with command line options and reader macros). The symbol is actually not case insensitive at all, it just appears that way because most of the symbols in your code are uppercased by the reader, unless you specially exempt them from that by surrounding them in bar characters or purposely configuring an environment with unusual reader options.

The net effect of all the above is that if you want to access a macro-generated symbol using the more familiar syntax, be sure to have all components uppercased before it's interned, e.g.:

```
(add-suffix-to-symbol q-sym "I")
```

instead of

```
(add-suffix-to-symbol q-sym "i")
```

Another option is to pass symbols to be concatenated rather than strings, e.g.

```
(defun add-suffix-to-symbol (sym suffix)
  (intern (concatenate 'string "" (string sym) "-" (string suffix))))

(print (add-suffix-to-symbol 'FOO 'bar)) ; foo-bar
(print (add-suffix-to-symbol 'foo '|bar|)) ; |FOO-bar| because foo is converted to FOO at read time
```

Answer (score 3):

To add a bit to Joe's answer:

Symbols are a datatype with names, values, a property list and they may be interned in a package (another Lisp data structure).

**Symbols preserve their namestring cases**

You can create a symbol with its name from a string and also ask for the name of the symbol. A function to make a symbol is, well, `make-symbol`:

```
CL-USER 8 > (make-symbol "This is A Symbol!!!***")
#:|This is A Symbol!!!***|

CL-USER 9 > (symbol-name (make-symbol "This is A Symbol!!!***"))
"This is A Symbol!!!***"
```

As you see the string is used as is and we get it out as it was provided. There is no case conversion.

**Escaping a symbol for the reader**

To print a symbol with different cases, whitespace and or special characters the symbol is escaped with surrounding `|` or single `\`:

```
CL-USER 11 > '|foo BAR ***# <>|
|foo BAR ***# <>|

CL-USER 12 > '\f\o\o\ BAR\ ***#\ <>
|foo BAR ***# <>|
```

**The reader is by default uppercasing unescaped input for symbol names**

The Lisp reader may use functions like `find-symbol` or `intern` to find or create symbols. Both can take a string as input and they are also case sensitive:

```
CL-USER 15 > (let ((symbol '|foo|))
               (eq (find-symbol "FOO") symbol))
NIL
```

But the reader itself (used for example via `read` and `read-from-string`) is not case sensitive by default. By default all symbols get uppercased:

```
CL-USER 21 > (symbol-name 'foo)
"FOO"

CL-USER 22 > (symbol-name 'FOO)
"FOO"

CL-USER 23 > (eq 'foo 'FOO)
T
```

We can check that both the printer and the reader are using uppercase by default:

```
CL-USER 35 > *print-case*
:UPCASE

CL-USER 36 > (readtable-case *readtable*)
:UPCASE
```

**When creating symbols in macros we usually want uppercase strings**

This means that when one creates symbols with names from strings, then one usually wants uppercase strings as input:

lowercase:

```
CL-USER 25 > (intern "zippy")
|zippy|
NIL
```

uppercase:

```
CL-USER 26 > (intern "ZIPPY")
ZIPPY
NIL
```

**In data we sometimes want mixed case symbols: escape them**

Sometimes we want to work with different cases: for example when the case needs to preserved because it is used as data:

```
CL-USER 27 > (defvar *parents* '(|Eva Luator| |Ben BitDiddle jr.|))
*PARENTS*

CL-USER 28 > *parents*
(|Eva Luator| |Ben BitDiddle jr.|)
```

**Creating uppercased symbol names with format**

Often in code one creates symbol names with `format` - which might be more concise than `concatenate`. One can then use `format` control strings, where the text or parts of it are uppercased by using `~:@(` and `~)`:

```
CL-USER 33 > (format nil "~:@(~a-~a-~a~)" "my" "macro" "name")
"MY-MACRO-NAME"

CL-USER 34 > (intern (format nil "~:@(~a-~a-~a~)" "my" "macro" "name"))
MY-MACRO-NAME
```